# PHP ftp_get failed to open stream when trying to download file

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to make the browser download a file from an FTP server, but whatever I try, I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: ftp_get(taak4.docx) [function.ftp-get]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/jamesmr117/domains/notepark.be/public_html/classes/taak.php on line 231

Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Error opening taak4.docx in /home/jamesmr117/domains/notepark.be/public_html/classes/taak.php on line 231
```

I am however 100% sure my FTP server is working fine, as uploading files works correctly. I also set every folder to chmod 777. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

My php code:

```
$local_file="taak4.dockx";
$server_file="taak4.dockx";
ftp_get($FTPClient->connectionId, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: And you're sure you have permissions to save the local file in the folder of your PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

you must specify the full path to the file. For example:

```
/var/home/victor/files/taak4.dockx
```

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for get document root dir path.

Comment: The files are directly in the script's path. I've tried this, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have write permission on the `$local_file` path. Make it a full path. Example: `chmod 777 /test` and make `$local_file` be like `/test/taak4.docx`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering from this issue even after changing the file permissions on my remote server i was not able to download it on my local server:

```
Warning: ftp_get(): Can't open Capture.PNG: No such file or directory in C:\MAMP\htdocs\ftp.php on line 25
```

**SOLUTION:**

One must include '/' before writing any path in the $server_file variable so the whole example that works just perfect is here:

```
// This is the path and new file name on my server (name can be different from the remote server file )
// if i want to save it just where my current php file is running ,no need to enter any path just file name
$local_file = 'capture.png';

// This is the path and file name on my Remote server from which i am downloading from
// this should start with '/' and write 'public_html' or 'htdocs' afterwards
$server_file = '/public_html/Capture.PNG';

// ftp details
$ftp_server="example.host.com";
$ftp_user_name="username";
$ftp_user_pass="password";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// This is to so that we do not time out
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```